# Touch ID with no prompt

Tags: ios, touch-id

I'm trying to use Touch ID for login authentication in an enterprise app. I was hoping to prompt the user with the default popup only once, then just add a label for any subsequent logins. "Use Touch ID or Enter PIN" (the way apple does it with the passcode). Does anyone know how to suppress the dialog box that appears with "evaluatePolicy"? I've seen other apps do it too, so It must be possible.

```
[localAuthenticationContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics localizedReason:localizedReasonString reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success)
    {
        // continue to app
        NSLog(@"SUCCEED!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        // go back to full login
        NSLog(@"error : %@", [error description]);
        errorCode(code);
        NSLog(@"FAILED!!!");
    }
}];
```

Comment: "I've seen other apps do it too, so It must be possible." Do you have any examples? I've not seen this before.